# Laravel Passport invalid scope(s) provided exception

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, laravel-6

- Laravel Passport version 8.0.0
- Laravel version: 6.2

I defined scopes of my API using the `Passport::tokensCan` method in the boot method of `AuthServiceProvider.php` file:

```
Passport::routes();

Passport::tokensCan([
    'view-posts' => 'View posts',
    'create-posts' => 'Create posts'
]);
```

Added the following middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    /*
    . . .
    */
    'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
    'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,
];
```

Then, I protected an API route in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::post('/posts', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@store',
    'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'scope:create-posts']
]);
```

In a client app, my authorization route is (`routes/web.php`):

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/auth/blogger', 'BloggerAuthController@redirect');
    Route::get('/auth/blogger/callback', 'BloggerAuthController@callback');
});
```

And `BloggerAuthController` controller is like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as Guzzle;

class BloggerAuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Guzzle $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function redirect()
    {
        $query = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => '3',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8001/auth/blogger/callback',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => 'view-posts'
        ]);

        return redirect('http://localhost:8000/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
    }

    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        $response = $this->client->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => '3',
                'client_secret' => 'gG5HcVn1JlGhzO0RfgTfWuqP8IVro1Qhu9g2q0Dq',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8001/auth/blogger/callback',
                'code' => $request->code
            ]
        ]);

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());

        $request->user()->token()->delete();

        $request->user()->token()->create([
            'access_token' => $response->access_token
        ]);

        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

When I (`POST`) request to `/api/posts` from my client app,
I get an exception:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid scope(s) provided.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\nbayramberdiyev\\Desktop\\fresh\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 206,
    /*
    . . .
    */
}
```

But the expected result would be:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

with status 401.

Why is this happening? Did I miss anything in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#token-scopes)?

Comment: you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to overwrite MissingScopeException exception to return whatever message you want and still scope Middleware in your route files

in Exception folder in Handler file in the render function

```
if ($exception instanceof MissingScopeException && $request->wantsJson()){
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Unauthenticated',
            ], 403);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Experiensed scenario of causing the issue**

So your issue is basically due to the conflict of a created token with new one base on allowed scope, base on my experience.

Let's say you've created a token base on a previous login attempt without scope/scopes, then you apply/include below code, and now you try to use application with defined scope in middleware but old token doesn't have defined with allowed scope, and in this case you get `Invalid Scope(s) Provided`

```
Passport::tokensCan([
    'view-posts' => 'View posts',
    'create-posts' => 'Create posts'
]);

Route::post('/posts', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@store',
    'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'scope:create-posts']
]);

$request->user()->token()->create([
   'access_token' => $response->access_token
]);
```

**What you're missing**

In other hand, there is a issue with create Token, since you should assign your scope to the created access token for example I'm trying to create a token, I can define like below :

```
$token = $user->createToken('authToken',['create-posts'])->accessToken;
```

This is one of the way of doing base on your login flow.

**This is totally ignoring the issue not fixing it **

There's another (from Mohammed Alama) answer which the code provided, It's not the answer to issue, and obviously It's just catching and customizing error message.

So make sure to use below code only for customizing return statement, since this is not the answer at all, and it's not fixing anything.

```
if ($exception instanceof MissingScopeException && $request->wantsJson()){
... return statement
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You requested for `view-posts` scope, but then tried to create a post which requires `create-posts` scope. That is the problem.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But in my case it should return a 401 response with a message `Unauthenticated.` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score -1):

When creating access_token, add scope: create-posts

```php
 $request->user()->token()->create([
            'access_token' => $response->access_token
        ], ['create-posts']);
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve this by adding middleware and validate the scope rather than using 'scopes:some_scope' in routes. Here is how I solved.

1. create a middleware and validate scope in a middleware like this.

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next){
   if (!$request->user()->tokenCan('user')) {
       return response()->json([
           'message' => "Unauthenticated",
       ]);
   }

   return $next($request);
   ```

   }
2. `request->user()->tokenCan('user')`  validate the scope.
   [image: I took an example from laravel documentation]
3. You can return the error message whatever you want.

   ```
   return response()->json([
       'message' => "Unauthenticated",
   ]);
   ```
4. Use middleware. I have been finding that answer and this is the best solution I can think of which is still in boundary and not too much work. If you did solve a better way, please share me too. I want to know too.